# How to fix Hive query issue with double and float type while checking condition, (having trouble with casting)

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm trying to run a basic hive query that selects for values above a threshold. The column type named "corr_coeff" is type float however the hive query language through hiveview2.0 or through zepelin (via JDBC Drive) always passes my equality check as a double and I get errors.

> FilterPredicate column: corr_coeff's declared type (java.lang.Double) does not match the schema found in file metadata. Column corr_coeff is of type: FLOAT

I tried setting a new variable for the threshold and casting it however this doesn't work either.

```
set PROB_THRESH=(cast 0.70 as float);
select corr_coeff FROM trends where trends.corr_coeff>PROB_THRESH;
```

Then I get the error:

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:54 Invalid table alias or column reference 'PROB_THRESH': (possible column names are: index, filename, start_trnd, end_trnd, start_trnd_time, end_trnd_time, feature1, feature2, corr_coeff)

#### Edit: update 8/21

So I found out that it will work if I cast the **entire column** originally a float as a double but this is a waste of resources.

```
set PROB_THRESH=0.70;
select corr_coeff FROM trends WHERE cast(trends.corr_coeff as double) >${hiveconf:PROB_THRESH};
```

What I want instead but always fails is to cast the **threshold value** in the comparison as a float because Hive initializes the variable as a double

```
use fca_analytics;
set PROB_THRESH=0.70;
select corr_coeff FROM trends WHERE trends.corr_coeff > cast(${hiveconf:PROB_THRESH} as float);
```

**This fails:**

> FilterPredicate column: corr_coeff's declared type (java.lang.Double) does not match the schema found in file metadata. Column corr_coeff is of type: FLOAT
>   Valid types for this column are: [class java.lang.Float]

Answer (score 0):

`PROB_THRESH` is a Hive variable.

Hive variables are referred using the following syntax, `${hiveconf:myvariable}`

So, your code must be modified to,

```
set PROB_THRESH=0.70;
select corr_coeff FROM trends where trends.corr_coeff > ${hiveconf:PROB_THRESH};
```

You can read more about hive variables on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution

Comment: I entered the hiveconf namespace as you suggested but I still have an issue with double when it's expecting a float type.   When I try to set PROB_THRESH=(cast 0.70 as float), I get errors. How do I declare PROB_THRESH as a float?